# Exporting cloudwatch logs to s3 glacier

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

I wanted to export my **older cloudwatch logs to s3 glacier** using my lambda function. I have found tutorials to exporting them to s3 bucket and then using a lifecycle policy to send them to s3 glacier. But instead of using s3 bucket as an intermediate, I wanted to know how can I send them over to s3 glacier directly? Is this possible?

I have looked for the *CreateExportTaskCommand* of *AWS cloudwatch module* to export the logs directly but it only exports to a s3 bucket, I guess which isn't much helpful.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way to export from CloudWatch logs to s3 glacier. If you look at the API [upload_archive](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glacier/client/upload_archive.html) takes vault and bytes as an input. Thus, you need to have your logs as bytes somewhere present. If you create your own Lambda function, you need to download them to your local storage from somewhere (i.e. s3). Or you can use a CLI or SDK to read your logs from a file [AWS CLI glacier upload_archive](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/glacier/upload-archive.html) and pass the blob in the `--body` parameter:

```
aws glacier upload-archive --vault-name MY_GLACIER_VAULT --account-id 123435569 --body file://tmp/my_older_cloudwatch_logs.zip
```

or with boto3

```py
import boto3

# Initialize the Glacier client
glacier_client = boto3.client('glacier')

# Set the name of the Glacier vault and the path to the file to be uploaded
vault_name = 'my-glacier-vault'
file_path = '/path/to/my/file.txt'

# Upload the file to Glacier
with open(file_path, 'rb') as f:
    archive_data = f.read()
response = glacier_client.upload_archive(vaultName=vault_name, body=archive_data)

# Print the archive ID
print(f"Archive ID: {response['archiveId']}")
```

Edit: did not see nodejs tag: here is an example

```js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const fs = require('fs');

// Initialize the Glacier client
const glacier = new AWS.Glacier({ region: 'us-east-1' });

// Set the name of the Glacier vault and the path to the file to be uploaded
const vaultName = 'my-glacier-vault';
const filePath = '/path/to/my/file.txt';

// Upload the file to Glacier
const archiveData = fs.readFileSync(filePath);
glacier.uploadArchive({ vaultName, body: archiveData }, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log(`Archive ID: ${data.archiveId}`);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Yeah guess will have to do it this way